# The catalog price rules cause error when re-indexing in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, catalog-price-rules

When I created a Catalog Price Rule in the admin and click Save, I got the error below but it's still saved. Then I tried to re-index via SSH and got the same error message.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\ConditionsToSearchCriteriaMapper::reverseSqlOperatorInFilter()
> must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\Filter, instance of
> Magento\Framework\Api\CombinedFilterGroup given, called in
> /vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/ConditionsToSearchCriteriaMapper.php
> on line 114 and defined in
> /vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/ConditionsToSearchCriteriaMapper.php:193

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Thank you so much for any solutions.

Comment: Have you found any solution?